# How to return correct array length after all the elements have been pushed in async/await used in map()?

Tags: javascript, async-await

When I use the map object to push the results of async/await to all elements in an array, I want to return after all the elements have been pushed.

Here's a sample code:

```
const obj = {
 'a': '1234',
 'b': '5678'
}

const balances = []

Object.keys(obj).map(async (key, index) => {
    const r = await getBalance(obj[key]) // async/await function to get balance of user id
    balances.push(Math.floor(r))
    console.log(balances.length)
})

console.log(balances.length)
```

output will be something like this:

```
0 
0 
1
2
```

How to `return balances` with correct `array.length = 2` after map() function?

Comment: Also relevant: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: As a side note - please don't use `.map()` for simple iteration. You can use `.forEach` or even a normal loop for that. In this case you actually do need a `.map()` but not as iteration but to convert to promises which you can then use with `Promise.all()` - something like `balances = await Promise.all( Object.values(obj).map(value => Math.floor(getBalance(value)) );` After that async operation completes you can check `balances.length`.

Comment: Yeah, more specifically see @VLAZ profile.

Comment: Try using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ. It helps and your sample code just work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code.

```js
const obj = {
    'a': '1234',
    'b': '5678'
}

// Sample getBalance function which is returns a promise.
async function getBalance(v) {
    return await v;
}

const balances = []

const promises = Object.keys(obj).map(async (key, index) => {
    const r = await getBalance(obj[key]);

    return Math.floor(Number(r))
})
Promise.all(promises).then(balances => {
    console.log(balances)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`.forEach()` or `.map()` doesn’t respect async/await at all, and `Promise.all` only works if the order of execution doesn’t matter. The `for...of` loop executes in the order one would expect — waiting on each previous `await` operation to complete before moving on to the next.

```js
const obj = {
    'a': '1234',
    'b': '5678'
}

// Sample getBalance function which is returns a promise.
async function getBalance(v) {
    return await v;
}

const balances = []

const getData = async () => {
    for(const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        const r = await getBalance(obj[key]);
        balances.push(Math.floor(r));
        console.log(balances.length);
    }
    console.log(balances.length);
};

getData();
```